# Can anyone explain to me how these constants in win32con are picked apart?

Tags: python, win32con

What I'm trying to do is find out what is fullscreen or exclusive fullscreen. The code I have is to generate the styles of the open windows on my desktop. WS_MAXIMIZE has a different numbers then what is being printed by the code. Can someone explain to me how these numbers are being generated by windows?

SO you know Siper-Man is exclusive fullscreen, and pot player is fullscreen while playing a video.

```py
from win32gui import GetWindowLong, GetWindowText
from pyvda import AppView, get_apps_by_z_order  # noqa
from datetime import datetime
import win32con
import inspect

# Spider-Man: Exclusive Fullscreen
tinmestamp = datetime.now().timestamp()
while datetime.now().timestamp() - tinmestamp < 10:
    continue

with open('GWL.txt', 'w') as file:
    for key, value in [member for member in inspect.getmembers(win32con) if 'GWL' in member[0]]:
        file.write(f'{key + ": int":35} = {value}\n')

with open('256.txt', 'w') as file:
    for key, value in [member for member in inspect.getmembers(win32con) if member[1] == 256]:
        file.write(f'{key + ": int":35} = {value}\n')

with open('WS.txt', 'w') as file:
    for key, value in [member for member in inspect.getmembers(win32con) if member[0].startswith('WS_')]:
        file.write(f'{key + ": int":35} = {value}\n')

with open('win32con.txt', 'w') as file:
    for key, value in [member for member in inspect.getmembers(win32con) if member[0].isupper()]:
        file.write(f'{key + ": int":35} = {value}\n')


print(f'{"MAXIMIZED":>12}')
windows = [window for window in get_apps_by_z_order(current_desktop = False) if (GetWindowLong(window.hwnd, win32con.GWL_STYLE) & win32con.WS_MAXIMIZE)]
for window in windows:
    print(f'{GetWindowText(window.hwnd)}')
print()

print(f'{"GWL_STYLE":>12}')
for window in get_apps_by_z_order(current_desktop = False):
    print(f'{GetWindowLong(window.hwnd, win32con.GWL_STYLE):<15} {GetWindowText(window.hwnd)}')
print()

print(f'{"GWL_EXSTYLE":>14}')
for window in get_apps_by_z_order(current_desktop = False):
    print(f'{GetWindowLong(window.hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE):<15} {GetWindowText(window.hwnd)}')
```

```
output:

   MAXIMIZED
MonitorPowerUtility – topmost.py
Alienware Command Center

   GWL_STYLE
369098752       Marvel's Spider-Man Remastered v2.616.0.0
399441920       MonitorPowerUtility – topmost.py
-1781596160     Alienware Command Center
382664704       Can anyone explain to me how these constants in win32con are picked apart? - Stack Overflow — Mozilla Firefox
-1764818944     FBI - S02E14 - Studio Gangster.mkv - PotPlayer

   GWL_EXSTYLE
8               Marvel's Spider-Man Remastered v2.616.0.0
256             MonitorPowerUtility – topmost.py
2097408         Alienware Command Center
256             Can anyone explain to me how these constants in win32con are picked apart? - Stack Overflow — Mozilla Firefox
262416          FBI - S02E14 - Studio Gangster.mkv - PotPlayer
```

```
Generated WS.txt file:

WS_ACTIVECAPTION: int               = 1
WS_BORDER: int                      = 8388608
WS_CAPTION: int                     = 12582912
WS_CHILD: int                       = 1073741824
WS_CHILDWINDOW: int                 = 1073741824
WS_CLIPCHILDREN: int                = 33554432
WS_CLIPSIBLINGS: int                = 67108864
WS_DISABLED: int                    = 134217728
WS_DLGFRAME: int                    = 4194304
WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES: int              = 16
WS_EX_APPWINDOW: int                = 262144
WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE: int               = 512
WS_EX_COMPOSITED: int               = 33554432
WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP: int              = 1024
WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT: int            = 65536
WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME: int            = 1
WS_EX_LAYERED: int                  = 524288
WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL: int                = 4194304
WS_EX_LEFT: int                     = 0
WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR: int            = 16384
WS_EX_LTRREADING: int               = 0
WS_EX_MDICHILD: int                 = 64
WS_EX_NOACTIVATE: int               = 134217728
WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT: int          = 1048576
WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY: int           = 4
WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: int         = 768
WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW: int            = 392
WS_EX_RIGHT: int                    = 4096
WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR: int           = 0
WS_EX_RTLREADING: int               = 8192
WS_EX_STATICEDGE: int               = 131072
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW: int               = 128
WS_EX_TOPMOST: int                  = 8
WS_EX_TRANSPARENT: int              = 32
WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE: int               = 256
WS_GROUP: int                       = 131072
WS_HSCROLL: int                     = 1048576
WS_ICONIC: int                      = 536870912
WS_MAXIMIZE: int                    = 16777216
WS_MAXIMIZEBOX: int                 = 65536
WS_MINIMIZE: int                    = 536870912
WS_MINIMIZEBOX: int                 = 131072
WS_OVERLAPPED: int                  = 0
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: int            = 13565952
WS_POPUP: int                       = -2147483648
WS_POPUPWINDOW: int                 = -2138570752
WS_SIZEBOX: int                     = 262144
WS_SYSMENU: int                     = 524288
WS_TABSTOP: int                     = 65536
WS_THICKFRAME: int                  = 262144
WS_TILED: int                       = 0
WS_TILEDWINDOW: int                 = 13565952
WS_VISIBLE: int                     = 268435456
WS_VSCROLL: int                     = 2097152
```

Comment: Hint: Print them as hexidecimal values. Or better yet, as binary.